# Как расширить интерфейс, прописанный в .d.ts?

Tags: typescript, angular2, jasmine

Не получается [добавить Matcher к декларации](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/angular2-tiddle/blob/master/src/auth.http.spec.ts) Jasmine

```
// /typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts
declare namespace jasmine {
  ...
  interface Matchers {
    ...
  }
}

// /src/auth.http.spec.ts
// расширяю декларацию 
declare namespace jasmine{
  interface Matchers {
    toBeAnInstanceOf(expected: any): boolean;
  }
}

describe('AuthHttp', ()=> {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
      toBeAnInstanceOf: // тело проверки
      });
  });


  it('provides an instance of AuthHttp as Http', inject([Http], (http) => {
    expect(http).toBeAnInstanceOf(AuthHttp); // Property 'toBeAnInstanceOf' does not exist on type 'Matchers'.
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использовал такой подход, позаимствованный из кода angular2 (они почему-то решили убрать NgMatchers из библиотеки, пришлось выкручиваться)

```
interface NgMatchers extends jasmine.Matchers {
  toBeAnInstanceOf(expected: any): boolean;
}
declare function expect(actual: any): NgMatchers;
```